# transfere file from local to ftp server in c#

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to transfere a file from local to ftp (File Transfer Protocol) server, normaly it works with a small file , but if i have a big size of file i have this probleme ("The connection to the server was reset while the page loads")

this is my code :

```
            //FTP Server URL.
            string ftp = ipFTP;

            //FTP Folder name. Leave blank if you want to upload to root folder.
            string ftpFolder = dossier_DAO;

            byte[] fileBytes = null;

            //Read the FileName and convert it to Byte array.
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
            {
                fileBytes = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            try
            {
                //Create FTP Request.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + fileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                //Enter FTP Server credentials.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(loginFTP, pwdFTP);
                request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
                request.EnableSsl = false;

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();
                }

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                //lblMessage.Text += fileName + " uploaded.<br />";


                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the connection for big files?

Comment: i have this message on the browser: "The connection to the server was reset while the page loads".

Comment: Did you google the error message already? And have you tried suggested solutions?

Comment: i did not find any suggestion for my question when i googled it

Comment: it's just happend when i browse a file with a big size then i lose connexion

Comment: Can you show your config file?

Comment: I JUST FIND A SOLUTION, i must add max size in web config <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />

Comment: yea, I was thinking about that, that's why I asked you to show your config file.

Comment: thank's Dylan Slabbinck for your help (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must add this code in the web config :

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="900000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```